# Shortcuts to mapped network drive do not work until after I open the network drive

Tags: windows, networking, mapped-drive

I mapped a network drive in Windows and I created shortcuts to some directories in the network drive. However, those shortcuts do not work if I haven't recently accessed the mapped network drive in Windows Explorer. If I try to go directly to a folder on the network drive via a shortcut file, Windows tells me that the location does not exist and asks if I want to delete the shortcut. After clicking on the mapped network drive (on the left panel in Windows Explorer) to open it, then all the shortcuts start working. Is there some way to make Windows recognize the mapped drive automatically so that the shortcuts work?

Comment: You are probably SOL with that.  Try using shortcuts that aren't mapped through a network drive first.. shortcuts that use only UNC paths.  That might wake the connection up.